# become registered user after starting out as unregistered user

Tags: discussion, support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

I began participating in this website, which I like very much, as an unregistered user. I went to register and this Open ID thing came up. So I registered with Open ID.

Since my username appeared at the top of the SO screen, I thought all was good with my registration.

Not so. When I went to verify my email address, SO registered me as some number (member 637005) but it has zdvdla as my Open ID user name. I really would like to keep my initial posts connected to the correct username.

I can still get to my old questions, reputation, privileges, etc., but want them associated with my correct name and email, not the one with the number...

Comment: What's your other account number?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, with an 'anonymous' and subsequently registered account. The solution is actually very simple... I sent an email to team@stackoverflow.com with links to both profiles, asking for them to be merged.

A few hours later, I received a reply letting me know that the accounts were merged.

I'm not aware of any automated way to do this at the moment.

*As a side note, this question is much better suited to http://meta.stackoverflow.com as it isn't related to programming. The Meta site is for questions relating to the site itself. No need to delete this question though, I'll vote for it to be moved, and am sure I won't be the first. :)*